# What is the @InlineOnly annotation?

Tags: kotlin

I [often](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt) [see](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Charsets.kt#L13) [the](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/regex/RegexExtensions.kt) [`@InlineOnly`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/internal/Annotations.kt#L60) annotation when browsing Kotlin's stdlib. As far as I recall the annotation only happens to be on `inline` functions. What is the purpose of this annotation? Isn't it obvious that `inline` functions are always inlined? It's documentation isn't really helpful

> Specifies that this function should not be called directly without inlining

Is it possible for inline functions to be called not inline?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote an answer found [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-does-synchronized-work/1528):

> InlineOnly means that the Java method corresponding to this Kotlin
>   function is marked private so that Java code can not access it (which
>   is the only way to call an inline function without actually inlining
>   it).

This annotation is `internal` only because

> This annotation was added in the last moment before release, so we hadn't time to validate the design and decided to keep it internal for a while. There are good chances we make it public later.