# Kotlin IllegalAccessError with += and -= for delegated Interface

Tags: kotlin

I've defined this class:

```
class NeverNullMap<K, V>(private val backing: MutableMap<K, V> = mutableMapOf(), val default: () -> V): MutableMap<K, V> by backing {
    override operator fun get(key: K): V = backing.getOrPut(key, default)
}
```

And I can use it perfectly fine like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myMap = NeverNullMap<String, Int> {0}
    println(myMap["test"])
    myMap["test"] = myMap["test"] + 10
    println(myMap["test"])
}
```

as expected the output is:

```
0
10
```

But when I try to change it to:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myMap = NeverNullMap<String, Int> {0}
    println(myMap["test"])
    myMap["test"] += 10
    println(myMap["test"])
}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.set(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V from class Day08Kt
    at Day08Kt.main(Day08.kt:10)
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:

Digging a bit into decompiled code both get compiled to completly diffrent code.

In the working version without the `+=` it gets compiled to:

```
  Map var2 = (Map)myMap;
  String var3 = "test";
  Integer var4 = ((Number)myMap.get("test")).intValue() + 10;
  var2.put(var3, var4);
```

The non working version gets compiled to:

```
MapsKt.set(myMap, "test", ((Number)myMap.get("test")).intValue() + 10);
```

So it calles this function: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L175

I still have no idea why that produces the Error, just why the first version behaves diffrently.

Edit: [YouTrack link to the report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21724)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: yes, this is a bug, it has been merged with [KT-14227](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14227):

> Incorrect code is generated when using `MutableMap.set` with `plusAssign` operator

---

After compilation (or decompilation, in this case), `MapsKt.set` is turned into a `private` method:

```
@InlineOnly
private static final void set(@NotNull Map $receiver, Object key, Object value) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($receiver, "$receiver");
    $receiver.put(key, value);
}
```

This explains the `IllegalAccessError`.

<s>Now, as to why it is private, I'm only speculating, but I feel like it may be due to this:</s>

[@usbpc102](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4284268/usbpc102) pointed out that [`@InlineOnly` is indeed the reason for the method being `private`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-does-synchronized-work/1528/2).

`@InlineOnly` specifies that the method should never be called directly:

> Specifies that this function should not be called directly without inlining

so I feel like this is a case where the call to `set` *should* have been inlined, but it was not.

Had the call been inlined, you would have ended up with compiled code that is practically identical to the working version, since the method only contains a call to `put`.

I suspect this is due to a compiler bug.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So I probably found a bug in the kotlin Compiler?

Comment: @usbpc102 It seems like you have, though it does seem odd that this would occur

Comment: I just checked and your assumption [why it is private is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763075/what-is-the-inlineonly-annotation)

Comment: @usbpc102 ah, thank you for the reference :) So it seems the intent is indeed to only allow inlining of the method. Since this does not occur here I think it is safe to call this a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm on my way reporting it to jetbrains :)